# What is similar code Buffer.from("String","hex") in flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart

What does this code do with the below example?

I have the below code in node.js and I want to do the same code in a flutter.

```
var iv = 'any string';
iv = new Buffer.from(iv, "hex");
```

Comment: Instead of require people to understand both Node.JS and Dart, it would be easier if you just write what this code does with an example.

Comment: Discription change.

Comment: What do you want `iv` to be used for after the conversion? As far I can see, the `Buffer` does just represent binary data so something like `Uint8List` in Dart. But it is not easy to tell if this is the correct target type since you are going to use `iv` for something and it is important to know what type this code expect... So in short, we need A LOT more context! :)

Comment: ok I will add more detail here tomorrow.

Comment: Can we do more discussion in chat?@julemand101

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241019/flutter

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this package will help**[Buffer](https://pub.dev/packages/buffer)

Comment: already checked. but not found anything which I want.